# Recurrence in Math

Tags: c++, recurrence

Sorry this is my first time use stackoverflow.

I dont kow where is the mistake in my code.

Output that i want:

```
-1+3-5+7-9+11-13+15
RESULT : 8
```

But Output that is shown

```
-1+3-5+7-9+11-13+15
RESULT : 10
```

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int i, S, x, sign;
    S = 0;
    for (i = 1; i <= 8; i++) {
        if ((pow(-1, i - 1) == 1) && (i > 1)) {
            sign = -1;
        }
        if ((pow(-1, i - 1) != 1) && (i > 1)) {
            sign = 1;
            cout << "+";
        }
        if (i == 1) {
            sign = 1;
            cout << "-";
        }
        x = sign * (2 * i - 1);
        cout << x;
        S = S + x;
    }
    cout << "\n Result:" << S;
}
```

Comment: Learn how to use a debugger, and step through the code line by line while watching the variable values.

Comment: Well, you're off by 2... and you're only adding/subtracting odd numbers. which one's sign did you get wrong?

Comment: For `i == 1`: `sign = 1` and `cout << "-"` next to each other looks dubious.

Comment: You are also doing some operations twice even when not needed, use `if ... else ...` instead, like in [this (fixed) little example](http://ideone.com/wQN9xz) I just made.

Comment: thanks you for your advice

Answer (score 3):

problem is in the if condition block where you check `i==1`
in that loop you are making `sign=1` that should be `sign=-1`

Answer (score 2):

How about improving the logic like following?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i;
    bool sign = true; // signed/minus = true, non-signed/plus = false
    int ans = 0;

    for( i=1; i<=15; i=i+2){
        if( sign == true){
            cout << "-" << i;
            ans = ans - i;
        }
        else {
            cout << "+" << i;
            ans = ans + i;
        }
        sign = !sign;
    }
    cout << endl << "RESULT : " << ans << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It can be streamlined a little bit more actually, by not doing any output in the `if` or `else` paths, and instead do e.g. `cout << showpos << i;` after the else.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <math.h>
 using namespace std;
 int main() 
 {
   int i, S, x, sign;
   S = 0;
   for (i = 1; i <= 8; i++) {
     if ((pow(-1, i - 1) == 1) && (i > 1)) {
        sign = -1;
     }
     else
     if ((pow(-1, i - 1) != 1) && (i > 1)) {
        sign = 1;
       // cout << "+";
     }
     //else
     if (i == 1) {
        sign = -1;
        //cout << "-";
     }
     x = sign * (2 * i - 1);
     cout <<"\n"<<x;
     S = S + x;
    //cout<<"S is \n"<<S;
  }
  cout << "\n Result:" << S;
}
```

You have put wrong sign when `i==1`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're starting the calculation with a positive `sign` (but you're lying to yourself by printing `"-"`).

You can simplify the code and don't need to mess around with `pow` if you make the obervation that

```
pow(-1, k) == -1 * pow(-1, k-1)
```

Starting at `pow(-1,0)` (that is, `1`), you can write:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int sign = 1;  // sign will always hold pow(-1, i).
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 8; i++)
    {
        sign *= -1;
        if (sign > 0)  // Since sign starts at -1, we know that i > 1 here
        {
            std::cout << "+";
        }
        int term = sign * (2 * i - 1);
        std::cout << term;
        sum += term;
    }
    std::cout << " = " << sum << std::endl;
}
```